# Copy all JPG file in a directory to another directory in Python?

Tags: python

I want to copy all my JPG files in one directory  to a new directory.
How can I solve this in Python?I just start to learn Python.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Take a look at these questions which are similar to yours and try out one of the solutions- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951659/copy-files-in-folder-up-one-directory-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397752/copy-multiple-files-in-python

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Of course Python offers all the tools you need.  To copy files, you can use [`shutil.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy).  To find all JPEG files in the source directory, you can use [`glob.iglob()`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.iglob).

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

src_dir = "your/source/dir"
dst_dir = "your/destination/dir"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

Note that this will overwrite all files with matching names in the destination directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It can work success.But it seem doesn't work for the JPG files in child directory.If I want to get all JPG(include the child directory) How can make it?

Comment: @Seventeenager: You would need to use `os.walk()` to walk the whole directory tree – see the example in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following code

```
import shutil, os
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(f, 'dest_folder')
```

N.B.: You're in the current directory.
If You have a different directory, then add the path in the files list.
i.e:

```
files = ['/home/bucket/file1.txt', '/etc/bucket/file2.txt', '/var/bucket/file3.txt']
```

Comment: doesn't define source location as was requested

Comment: @Displayname Current directory is the source file.

Answer (score 3):

```
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*", "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

You should write "**" before "*.jpg" to search child directories. more "*" means more subdirectory to search

Answer (score 3):

```
import shutil 
import os 

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
       src_dir = "your/source/dir"
       dst_dir = "your/dest/dir"
       shutil.move(src_dir,dst_dir)
```

Comment: `os.listdir(path)` -- here `path` is not defined