# How to recover a damaged MsAccess Database?

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2010 and one of my databases on our shared network can't be opened any more with an "Unrecognized Database Format" error message. Is it possible to save somehow its data? Is there any tool to recover a corrupted MsAccess database?

Comment: I would check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884080/corrupted-access-accdb-file-unrecognized-database-format) and see if you can get anywhere. From there we can possibly narrow down a specific solution if other solutions were nonconstructive.

Comment: I've had issues where I get this message on specific machines but works fine on the other 99%.  Usually a reinstall of the database engine/runtime fixes it.  Also any chance your network drive keeps copies?