# MS Access Database Backup

Tags: database, ms-access, backup

I have uploaded the MS-Access database at a shared drive location in a Windows folder. For couple of days, the database works fine and then it automatically starts creating backup copies of the database every time users try to use the database. While the backup copies are created the size of parent database gets reduced from 10 Mb to 150-200 Kb.

When users try to open the database, they get the message -"Unrecognized database format '\10.10.5.7\Database\DB-R.accdb'

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

Online searches show this could be related to:
1. 64bit of Access vs 32bit version
2. The version of access you are running, if it is not patched

See related question:
[Simular Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884080/corrupted-access-accdb-file-unrecognized-database-format)

Comment: Kyle: Would you be in a position to recommend a solution

Comment: I would suggest first ensuring you have all MS patches for Access for the current version you are running. If that does not work, spin up a VM with either 64bit or 32bit access (whichever you are NOT running) fully patch it, then see if the problem persists.