# What is the recommended way to generate and copy some files to arbitrary places in a setup.py?

Tags: python, distutils, distribute, setup.py

I have a PyQT KDE application and I need to generate some files(with `pyuic` and `pyrcc` commands) and copy some files(.desktop) to some places(ie /usr/share/applications/kde4/). What are preferred ways to do this?

Is using `shutil.copy()` and `os.command()` (or `subprocess.Popen()`) good way to copy operations and commands? Or are there better ways to do this in setup.py with disutils?

Answer (score 1):

Judging [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) `shutil` is the way to go for copying files/directories (copyfile/copytree/...)

As for installing extra files with distutils, see the [data_files](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) and [package_data](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) options.