# Copying several files into new folder

Tags: python, copy

I have a folder containing several text files. How would I go about using python to make a copy of everyone of those files and put the copies in a new folder?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's easier to help when we know what you have done up to this point.

Answer (score 2):

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("abc", "copy of abc")
```

Source: [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the glob module to select your .txt files:

```
import os, shutil, glob

dst = 'path/of/destination/directory'
try:
    os.makedirs(dst) # create destination directory, if needed (similar to mkdir -p)
except OSError:
    # The directory already existed, nothing to do
    pass
for txt_file in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
    shutil.copy2(txt_file, dst)
```

The `glob` module only contains 2 functions: `glob` and `iglob` ([see documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)). They both  find all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, but `glob.glob` returns a list and `glob.iglob` returns a generator.

Comment: `makedirs(dst)` fails if the destination already exists, unlike `mkdir -p`

Comment: Good catch. I added exception handling around it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at this post: [How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

```
ls_dir = os.listdir(src_path)    
for file in ls_dir:
    copyfile(file, dest_path)
```

That should do it.

Comment: `os.system` is discouraged; `subprocess.call` is a recommended alternative: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#replacing-os-system

Comment: In this case, neither should be used. Python can read a directory listing just fine (and in a way that handles whitespace in filenames). `os.listdir()`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Tshepang and jordanm.  I updated my suggested answer accordingly.

Comment: Unless you will need `ls_dir` again, you can shorten this to `for file in os.listdir(src_path)`. I would also rather you avoid using a word like `file` for an arbitrary variable, since `file()` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Use shutil.copyfile

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```