# Python: save csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python (learning for 2 weeks only) and there's something I really can't even try (I have been googling for an hour and coulndn't find any).

`file1` and `file2` are both CSV files.

I've got a function that looks like:

```
def save(file1, file2):
```

it is for `file2` to have the same content as `file1`. For example, when I do:

```
save(file1, file2)
```

`file2` should have the same content as `file1`.

Thanks in advance and sorry for an empty code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you supposed to first *read* the file and *then* write it out again? If not, you may want to explore the [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) module and look for copy type operations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Python has a standard module [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) which is useful for these sorts of things.

If you need to write the code to do it yourself, simply open two files (the input and the output).  Loop over the file object, Reading lines from the input file and write them into the output file.

Comment: You're so fast. I don't know why I even try, ha

Comment: I know it's just something weird with how stackoverflow estimates or updates times but right now it says john asked this question 25 seconds ago and that you answered it 1 minute ago. Jon Skeet, is that you?

Comment: @IamChuckB -- You caught me.  I'm really Jon Skeet gaming the system to increase my already rediculous reputation.  Also I answered the question before it was asked because I can do that sort of thing (I am Jon Skeet after all :-p)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to copy a file you can do this:

```
def save(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(file2, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

this copies the file with name `file1` to the file with name `file2`. It really doesn't matter what the content of those files is.

Comment: It matters if `file1` is 10Gb in size. :)

Comment: Yeah, in this case you have to replace the `read`/`write` call with a loop and only read segments. But for a homework implementation this should do the job :)

Comment: Which brings up another good point -- on a homework question, do you really want to give the answer outright like this?

Comment: Actually if he's been googling for one hour he might never find the solution himself :( I typed in `python copy file howto` and the first hit with Google is http://stackoverflow.com/q/123198/589206 :) Maybe I should mark this question as a duplicate?