# Copy and move files in Python?

Tags: python, linux, shell, filesystems, copy

What's the best way to copy and move files in python to a different directory, and overwrite those files in the destination if they already exist?

Comment: Already [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
file1=open('insert directory here').readlines()
file2=open('insert directory here', 'w')
file2.write(file1)
```

If either of the directories have spaces in them do this:

```
directory='insert directory here'
directory=directory.rstrip()
```

Then use the variable directory as you would use the 'insert directory here'.