# netcdf4-python: Reading variable storage parameters

Tags: python, netcdf4

Im trying to manually copy all dimensions, variables and attribute of a NetCDF-file to a new file. As in [copy netcdf file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936563/copy-netcdf-file-using-python) this works well, except for the storage parameters like 'fill_value' or 'chunksizes'. In `ncdump -sch`, these parameters are shown with a leading underscore (_):

```
    float var1(time, lat, lon) ;
        var1:_FillValue = NaNf ;
        var1:grid_mapping = "crs" ;
        var1:unit = "m" ;
        var1:_Storage = "chunked" ;
        var1:_ChunkSizes = 1, 14, 146 ;
        var1:_DeflateLevel = 9 ;
        var1:_Shuffle = "true" ;
        var1:_Endianness = "little" ;
```

In [createVariable](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Dataset.createVariable) I can set these parameters for the new variable, but how can I obtain the parameters like 'fill_value' or 'chunksizes' from the existing file using the netcdf4-python module? What is the syntax to read those parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information about chunk sizes, you can use the `chunking()` method on variables. Unfortunately, it looks like you can only access `_FillValue` if it's been set to a non-default value:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

nc = Dataset('data.nc', 'w')
nc.createDimension('t', 10)
var = nc.createVariable('temp', 'f', ('t',), fill_value=80)
var[:] = np.arange(10)
nc.close()

nc_read = Dataset('data.nc')
temp = nc_read.variables['temp']
print(temp.chunking())
print(temp._FillValue)
```

So right now it looks like the easiest way to handle fill value is:

```
fill = getattr(temp, '_FillValue', mydefaultvalue)
```

Might be worth opening an issue upstream on [GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that works like a charm!
I've solved the handling of an undefined `_FillValue` now like:

```
try: fillVal = variable._FillValue
except: fillVal = netCDF4.default_fillvals[str(variable.dtype.kind)+str(variable.dtype.itemsize)]
```

Looks a bit complicated but it seems that `dtype` has no output format method for the expected input for `default_fillvals`