# Problems executing commands with (') character in python

Tags: python

I'm doing a program that copies some files from a music playlist. I execute the command just like this:

```
command =   'cp "%s" "%s"' % (songPath,plPath)
os.system(command)
```

The problem is that when I execute that if the song's path has a **'** character command can not be executed. It says:

> cp: cannot stat `/home/myname/Music/Oasis/(What\'s The Story) Morning Glory/03 Wonderwall.mp3': No such file or directory

I checked the songPath and has no \ character before the **'**
Does anyone know how to avoid the program adding that \ character?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how do you get `songPath` and `plPath`?

Comment: Why use `cp` through `system` instead of using Python's libraries to copy it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: @loganfsmyth -- That's a *really* good question.

Comment: I think you should accept @mgilson's answer though since that is the answer to the question as you asked it, even if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Use `subprocess.call` instead:

```
ret_val = subprocess.call(['cp',songPath,plPath])
```

This avoids the shell so your arguments should be passed the `cp` in the exact form that you gave them.

Comment: I have the same problem with subprocess.call, but shutil.copy2(songPath,plPath) solved the problem (thanks to @loganfsmyth)