# How to assign variable to listed items in python?

Tags: python

**What I want to do**

Go into the folder that the user selects, then show them the files from this folder

**How I would like I do this**

I would like to show the user a list of files and the folder they are contained in, and then allow the user to select one.

**Code**

I've tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, glob

os.chdir(glob.glob("/var/mobile/TP/")[0])
print("Please select a Texture Pack (##):")
items = os.listdir(".")
i = 1
for item in items:
        print("[%.2d] %s" % (i, item))
        i += 1
#And then something that will assign the variables to the listed items, like
*firstlisteditem*=a ; *secondlisteditem*=b #... and so on
#and then i need to get the user to tell me which folder he wants to go to. This I will do using a number. 
se=raw_input ()
if "1" in se then
exec /var/mobile/TP/$a
if "2" in se then
exec /var/mobile/TP/$b
```

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in this context? And by *listed item* do you mean the elements of `items` or the values you are printing? It's also worth noting counting in a `for` loop is a bad practice, instead, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: 'for i, item in enumerate(items):' instead of i = 1, and i+=1; make sure you change the print statement from i to i+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `items` is a list, you can access it by its index:

```
items = ['a','b','c']
print(items[0])
```

That will print `a`. For your example:

```
se=int(raw_input())

if se < len(items):
    item = items[se-1]
    the_path = "/var/mobile/TP/{}".format(item)
else:
    print("Please enter a value between 1 and {}".format(len(items)))
```

Comment: also consider: `os.path.join`

Comment: @EvženWybitul See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Plz how can I use just the name of the chosen item (u know, the_path is path of the item, but can I get just the last one in the path - how to setup a variable to it). Cause the path must be /var/mobile/TP/*thechosenitem*/*thesamenameaschosenitem*