# Python: Cannot copy file TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Tags: python, file, unicode

I have a list of text files named like "default_xxx.txt", for example: default_abc.txt, default_def.txt
I want to copy the file contents to another file, which is name "xxx.txt" stripping out the "default_".

Referring to the following answer of copying files in Python:
[How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)
Here's my code:

```html
import os
import shutil
import re
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../config/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt") and file.startswith("default_"):
            file_name = os.path.basename(os.path.join(root, file))
            file_name = re.sub(r'default_','',file_name)
            config_file = open(os.path.join(root,file_name), 'w+') 
            shutil.copy(file,config_file)
```

I got an error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gs2000_IAR\tools\automation\lib\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    shutil.copy(file,config_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 117, in copy
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Anyone's help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format code using the {} button. Thanks!

Comment: You may want copyfileobj(). See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the error message says,** `shutil.copy` takes strings: file *names* (well, paths), not open file objects.  So don't open the file.

```
shutil.copy(file, os.path.join(root,file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy), `shutil.copy` receives the *filenames*, not the contents. The error message is actually very clear about this mismatch.

So your next-to-last line should be just:

```
config_file = os.path.join(root,file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were sending the file handle as a parameter to `copy` instead of the filename. `open` creates and returns the file handle and not the name, which you don't want. Just lose the call to `open`.

```
import os
import shutil
import re
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("../config/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt") and file.startswith("default_"):
            file_name = os.path.basename(os.path.join(root, file))
            file_name = re.sub(r'default_','',file_name)
            config_filename = os.path.join(root,file_name)
            shutil.copy(file,config_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a naming conflict. 'file' is a python function, so you might want to rename the variable 'file'.

Comment: Although it would be good to not mask this name, this has nothing to do with the problem here.