# Copying and renaming excel files with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to copy an excel file and rename it. For example I have a file **`HI.xlsx`** and I want to copy it and rename it as **`BYE.xlsx`**.
My code to do this is below and when I run it, the file **`BYE.xlsx`** is created, but it is corrupted.

Here is what I am using:

```
fIn = open(r"HI.xlsx")
fOut = open(r"BYE.xlsx", "w")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be using [`shutil.copy()`:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)

```
shutil.copy("HI.xlsx", "BYE.xlsx")
```