# Scheduled, timestamped sqlite3 .backup?

Tags: django, sqlite, pythonanywhere

Running a small db on pythonanywhere, and am trying to set up a scheduled .backup of my sqlite3 database. Is there any way in the command line to add a time/date stamp to the filename, so that it doesn't overwrite the previous days backup?

Here's the code I'm using, if it matters:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
.backup dbbackup.sqlite3
.quit
```

Running every 24 hours. The previous day's backup gets overwritten, though. I'd love to just be able to save it as dbbackup.timestamp.sqlite3 or something, so I could have multiple backups available.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you executing that code?

Comment: Via pythonanywhere's scheduling service

Comment: Why not have their scheduling service run a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suggest you to handle this case with [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and cronjob.

This an example how to do it; save this file eg in `yourapp/management/commands/dbackup.py`, don't forget to add `__init__.py` files.

```
yourapp/management/__init__.py
yourapp/management/commands/__init__.py
yourapp/management/commands/dbackup.py
```

But, previously add these lines below to your `settings.py`

```
USERNAME_SUPERUSER = 'yourname`
PASSWORD_SUPERUSER = `yourpassword`
EMAIL_SUPERUSER = `youremail@domain.com`
DATABASE_NAME = 'db.sqlite3'
```

The important tree path project if you deploying at pythonanywhere;

```
/home/yourusername/yourproject/manage.py
/home/yourusername/yourproject/db.sqlite3
/home/yourusername/yourproject/yourproject/settings.py
/home/yourusername/yourproject/yourapp/management/commands/dbackup.py
```

Add these script below into `yourapp/management/commands/dbackup.py`, you also can custom this script as you need.

```
import os
import time
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import (BaseCommand, CommandError)

USERNAME_SUPERUSER = settings.USERNAME_SUPERUSER
PASSWORD_SUPERUSER = settings.PASSWORD_SUPERUSER
EMAIL_SUPERUSER = settings.EMAIL_SUPERUSER
DATABASE_NAME = settings.DATABASE_NAME #eg: 'db.sqlite3'


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ('Command to deploy and backup the latest database.')

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '-b', '--backup', action='store_true',
            help='Just backup command confirmation.'
        )

    def success_info(self, info):
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(info))

    def error_info(self, info):
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR(info))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        backup = options['backup']

        if backup == False:
            return self.print_help()

        # Removing media files, if you need to remove all media files
        # os.system('rm -rf media/images/')
        # self.success_info("[+] Removed media files at `media/images/`")

        # Removing database `db.sqlite3`
        if os.path.isfile(DATABASE_NAME):
            # backup the latest database, eg to: `db.2017-02-03.sqlite3`
            backup_database = 'db.%s.sqlite3' % time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            os.rename(DATABASE_NAME, backup_database)
            self.success_info("[+] Backup the database `%s` to %s" % (DATABASE_NAME, backup_database))

            # remove the latest database
            os.remove(DATABASE_NAME)
            self.success_info("[+] Removed %s" % DATABASE_NAME)

        # Removing all files migrations for `yourapp`
        def remove_migrations(path):
            exclude_files = ['__init__.py', '.gitignore']
            path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path)

            filelist = [
                f for f in os.listdir(path)
                if f.endswith('.py')
                and f not in exclude_files
            ]
            for f in filelist:
                os.remove(path + f)
            self.success_info('[+] Removed files migrations for {}'.format(path))

        # do remove all files migrations
        remove_migrations('yourapp/migrations/')

        # Removing all `.pyc` files
        os.system('find . -name *.pyc -delete')
        self.success_info('[+] Removed all *.pyc files.')

        # Creating database migrations
        # These commands should re-generate the new database, eg: `db.sqlite3`
        os.system('python manage.py makemigrations')
        os.system('python manage.py migrate')
        self.success_info('[+] Created database migrations.')

        # Creating a superuser
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username=USERNAME_SUPERUSER,
            password=PASSWORD_SUPERUSER,
            email=EMAIL_SUPERUSER
        )
        user.save()
        self.success_info('[+] Created a superuser for `{}`'.format(USERNAME_SUPERUSER))
```

Setup this command with crontab

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

And add these following below lines;

```
# [minute] [hour] [date] [month] [year]
59 23 * * * source ~/path/to/yourenv/bin/activate && cd ~/path/to/yourenv/yourproject/ && ./manage.py dbackup -b
```

---

**But**, if you need to deploy at pythonanywhere, you just need to add these..

Daily  at `[hour]` : `[minute]` UTC, ... fill the `hour=23` and `minute=59`

```
source /home/yourusername/.virtualenvs/yourenv/bin/activate && cd /home/yourusername/yourproject/ && ./manage.py dbackup -b
```

### Update 1

> I suggest you to update the commands to execute the file of `manage.py` such as `os.system('python manage.py makemigrations')` with function of `call_command`;

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('collectstatic', verbosity=3, interactive=False)
call_command('migrate', 'myapp', verbosity=3, interactive=False)
```

...is equal to the following commands typed in terminal:

```
$ ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput -v 3
$ ./manage.py migrate myapp --noinput -v 3
```

See [running management commands from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

### Update 2

Previous condition is if you need to re-deploy your project and using a fresh database. **But**, if you only want to backup it by renaming the database, you can using module of [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile)

```
import os
import time
import shutil
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import (BaseCommand, CommandError)

DATABASE_NAME = settings.DATABASE_NAME #eg: 'db.sqlite3'


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ('Command to deploy and backup the latest database.')

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '-b', '--backup', action='store_true',
            help='Just backup command confirmation.'
        )

    def success_info(self, info):
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(info))

    def error_info(self, info):
        return self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR(info))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        backup = options['backup']

        if backup == False:
            return self.print_help()

        if os.path.isfile(DATABASE_NAME):
            # backup the latest database, eg to: `db.2017-02-29.sqlite3`
            backup_database = 'db.%s.sqlite3' % time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            shutil.copyfile(DATABASE_NAME, backup_database)
            self.success_info("[+] Backup the database `%s` to %s" % (DATABASE_NAME, backup_database))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out and report back.

Comment: The code seems to work for renaming the db.sqlite3 to the db.currentdate.sqlite3, but then it does not restore the original db.sqlite3. Did I miss something?

Comment: simply way, you can use module `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`, related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/123212/6396981

Comment: That worked! Couple small changes (still needed from django.conf import settings in header, and there was an extra " ' " on line 29), but otherwise works perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: oh, I see.. I'll update it.. sorry about missing... you're welcome.. :)