# How to create a copy of a file within the same folder and rename it?

Tags: python, file, copy

Inside of 'Folder X' I would like to create a copy Invoice.xlsx which is already inside of Folder X and create a copy of it with a new name also inside of Folder X.

How is this done with Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the Stack Overflow search feature. This question has been answered already.

See [How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) for example.

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile("/path/to/folder X/Invoice.xslx", "/path/to/folder X/Invoice-Copy.xslx")
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be with `subprocess`, which lets you run shell commands:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cp', 'Invoice.xlsx', 'Invoice_2.xlsx'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read file
with open('Folder X/Invoice.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
    file = f.read()

# write file
with open('Folder X/Invoice_Copy.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file)
```