# How to copy a file to a specific folder in a Python script?

Tags: python, file, copy, filesystems, file-copying

I have the path of a file stored in a variable (say) filePath. I would like to copy that particular file to another specific folder within a Python script.

I tried

```
folderPath = (os.getcwd() + "/folder_name/") #to get the path of the folder
shutil.copyfile(filePath, folderPath)
```

But I got an error  `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`.

How can I solve this ?

My question might seem to be  a duplicate of [How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)
. But actually, I want to copy a file to a **folder/directory** whereas most answers to that question mention copying one file to another **file**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `shutil.copy(filePath, folderPath)` instead of `shutil.copyfile()`. This will allow you to specify a folder as the destination and copies the file including permissions.

> `shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)`:
>
> Copies the file src to the file or directory dst. src and dst should be strings. If dst specifies a directory, the file will be copied into dst using the base filename from src. Returns the path to the newly created file.
>
> ...
>
> **copy() copies the file data and the file’s permission mode** (see os.chmod()). Other metadata, like the file’s creation and modification times, is not preserved. To preserve all file metadata from the original, use copy2() instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

See the difference in copying also documented in `shutil.copyfile()` itself:

> `shutil.copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)`:
>
> **Copy the contents (no metadata)** of the file named src **to a file named dst** and return dst. src and dst are path names given as strings. dst must be the complete target file name; **look at shutil.copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory path**. If src and dst specify the same file, SameFileError is raised.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Comment: Yeah,this also works :)

Answer (score 2):

`folderpath` must be a file, not a directory. The error says it all. Do something like:

```
shutil.copyfile(filePath, folderPath+'/file_copy.extension')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:

```
folderPath = os.path.join('folder_name', os.path.basename(filePath))
shutil.copyfile(filePath, folderPath)
```