# How to copy zipfile from one folder to another folder using Python

Tags: python

Please don't mark the question as a duplicate. I have tried multiple questions and it didn't work for me. hence I am raising a new question.

Problem :

I am trying to copy a list of zip files from my source to the destination folder.I have tried using shutil.copy and shutil.copyfile but I don't see the file getting copied into my destination folder. Can someone help me if I am doing anything wrong or is there any other way of handling zip files. Following is my script and I don't see any error while executing the script. I am running on a Linux machine.

```
import os,shutil,time
source="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobA/build-output"
destination="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobA/m_output"
mod_files = ["file_1.zip","file_2.zip","file_3.zip","Folder_A","Folder_B"]
os.chdir(source)
if len(mod_files) != 0:
    for file in mod_files:
        if file in os.listdir(source) and file.endswith(".zip"):
            try:
                shutil.copy(file, destination)
                time.sleep(10)
                print("Copied ---- {} ---- to ---- {} ---- \n\n".format(file,
                                                                        destination))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception occurred while copying the file to destination \n {}".format(e))
        else:
            raise Exception("{} bundle doesn\'t exist in {} ".format(file, source))
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Questions tried

1. [How do I copy an entire directory of files into an existing directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868714/how-do-i-copy-an-entire-directory-of-files-into-an-existing-directory-using-pyth)
2. [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)
3. [How to copy a file to a specific folder in a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126572/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-specific-folder-in-a-python-script)

Comment: If you have tried other questions/ answers please include them in your question, so that your questions is not flagged as duplicate.

Comment: OK.I will update the question with whatever i have tried

Comment: Try os.system('cp -r {} {}'.format(file, destination)) instead of shutil.copy may helps

Comment: Also `/var` is usually sudo only, do you have the according write rights to copy into `/var`?

Comment: Start with the simplest code that will copy a file.  Make sure that works.  Write a loop that will iterate all of your files.  Make sure that works.  Combine.  Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the argument you have give for `source` for the function `shutil.copy`, so change `shutil.copy(file, destination)` to `shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), destination)`

Try the code below,

```
import os,shutil
import time
source = "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobA/build-output"
destination = "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobA/m_output"
mod_files = ["file_1.zip","file_2.zip","file_3.zip","Folder_A","Folder_B"]
if len(mod_files) != 0:
    for file in mod_files:
        if file in os.listdir(source) and file.endswith(".zip"):
            try:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), destination)
                time.sleep(10)
                print("Copied ---- {} ---- to ---- {} ---- \n\n".format(file,
                                                                        destination))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception occurred while copying the file to destination \n {}".format(e))
        else:
            raise Exception("{} bundle doesn\'t exist in {} ".format(file, source))
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```