# How to execute a python script in a different directory?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

**Solved** see my answer below for anyone who might find this helpful.

I have two scripts a.py and b.py.
In my current directory "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\MAIN", I run > python a.py.

The first script, a.py runs in my current directory, does something to a bunch of files and creates a new directory (testA) with the edited versions of those files which are simultaneously moved into that new directory. Then I need to run b.py for the files in testA.

As a beginner, I would just copy and paste my b.py script into testA and execute the command again "> python b.py", which runs some commands on those new files and creates another folder (testB) with those edited files.

I am trying to eliminate the hassle of waiting for a.py to finish, move into that new directory, paste b.py, and then run b.py. I am trying to write a bash script that executes these scripts while maintaining my hierarchy of directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 python a.py && python b.py
```

Script a.py runs smoothly, but b.py does not execute at all. There are no error messages coming up about b.py failing, I just think it cannot execute because once a.py is done, b.py does not exist in that NEW directory.
Is there a small script I can add within b.py that moves it into the new directory? I actually tried changing b.py directory paths as well but it did not work.

For example in b.py:

```
mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the same path as a.py
mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir+"\\testA")
```

I changed mydirs to mydir_new in all instances within b.py, but that also made no difference...I also don't know how to move a script into a new directory within bash.

As a little flowchart of the folders:

```
MAIN # main folder with unedited files and both a.py and b.py scripts
|
| (execute a.py)
|
--------testA # first folder created with first edits of files
         |
         | (execute b.py)
         |
         --------------testB # final folder created with final edits of files
```

TLDR: How do I execute a.py and b.py from the main test folder (bash script style?), if b.py relies on files created and stored in testA. Normally I copy and paste b.py into testA, then run b.py - but now I have 200+ files so copying and pasting is a waste of time.

Comment: access a module in the directory above your current directory with `..module_name`

Comment: I got b.py to work now while staying in my main directory. The bash script does not execute b.py however once a.py is done.
If I type "python a.py", then "python b.py" it works though. Not sure why "python a.py & python b.py" does not do the same thing.

Comment: Nevermind I got it finally, it was just a stupid typo!
having "python a.py & python b.py" does work in the bash script!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### The easiest answer is probably to change your working directory, then call the second `.py` file from where it is:

```
python a.py && cd testA && python ../b.py
```

---

#### Of course you might find it even easier to write a script that does it all for you, like so:

Save this as `runTests.sh` in the same directory as `a.py` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
python a.py
cd testA
python ../b.py
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x ./runTests.sh
```

Then you can simply enter your directory and run it:

```
./runTests.sh
```

Comment: Sorry I am not that adept in linux but I am learning. I run the chmod command first in my cmd window, then I execute runTests.sh? The chmod line is confusing me as I've never used that before.
I want to try your method as well (in addition to my own which is probably not the BEST since it does involve changing the b.py script a bit)

Comment: Oh it worked! Is the chmod something that needs to be typed every time or can that also be part of the bash script?

Comment: The `chmod` line is run once. This tells the system that it's an executable file, and that it's allowed to execute it. It should only need to be run once on each file you want to make executable unless you've run the opposite `chmod -x` command on the file, which would tell the system it's not allowed to execute it.

Comment: For some reason, it just adds /../ in the path and I get `Errno 2`

Answer (score 11):

I managed to get b.py executing and producing the testB folder where I need it to, while remaining in the MAIN folder. For anyone who might wonder, at the beginning of my b.py script I would simply use mydir = os.getcwd() which normally is wherever b.py is.

To keep b.py in MAIN while making it work on files in other directories, I wrote this:

```
mydir = os.getcwd() # would be the MAIN folder
mydir_tmp = mydir + "//testA" # add the testA folder name
mydir_new = os.chdir(mydir_tmp) # change the current working directory
mydir = os.getcwd() # set the main directory again, now it calls testA
```

Running the bash script now works!

Comment: why do you use two forward slashes? backslashes on windows need another to escape, but double forward slashes are meaningless.

Comment: See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191881/why-do-i-have-double-slash-here)

Answer (score 3):

In your batch file, you can set the %PYTHONPATH% variable to the folder with the Python module. This way, you don't have to change directories or use pushd to for network drives. I believe you can also do something like

```
set "PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;c:\the path\to\my folder\which contains my module"
```

This will append the paths I believe (This will only work if you already have set %PYTHONPATH% in your environment variables).

If you haven't, you can also just do

```
set "PYTHONPATH=c:\the path\to\my folder\which contains my module"
```

Then, in the same batch file, you can do something like

```
python -m mymodule ...
```

Answer (score 1):

despite there are already answers i still wrote a script out of fun and it still could be of help in some respects.
I wrote it for python3, so it is necessary to tweak some minor things to execute it on v2.x (e.g. the prints).

Anyways... the code creates a new folder relative to the location of a.py, creates and fills script b.py with code, executes b and displays b's results and errors.

The resulting path-structure is:
testFolder
|-testA
| |-a.py
|-testB
| |-b.py

The code is:

```
import os, sys, subprocess

def getRelativePathOfNewFolder(folderName):
    return "../" + folderName + "/"

def getAbsolutePathOfNewFolder(folderName):
    # create new folder with absolute path:
    #   get path of current script:
    tmpVar = sys.argv[0]
    #   separate path from last slash and file name:
    tmpVar = tmpVar[:sys.argv[0].rfind("/")]
    #   again to go one folder up in the path, but this time let the slash be:
    tmpVar = tmpVar[:tmpVar.rfind("/")+1]
    #   append name of the folder to be created:
    tmpVar += folderName + "/"

    # for the crazy ones out there, you could also write this like this:
    # tmpVar = sys.argv[0][:sys.argv[0].rfind("/", 0, 
    sys.argv[0].rfind("/")-1)+1] + folderName + "/"
    return tmpVar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do stuff here:
    # ...
    # create new folder:
    bDir = getAbsolutePathOfNewFolder("testB")
    os.makedirs(bDir, exist_ok=True) # makedirs can create new nested dirs at once. e.g: "./new1/new2/andSoOn"
    # fill new folder with stuff here:
    # ...
    # create new python file in location bDir with code in it:
    bFilePath = bDir + "b.py"
    with open(bFilePath, "a") as toFill:
        toFill.write("if __name__ == '__main__':")
        toFill.write("\n")
        toFill.write("\tprint('b.py was executed correctly!')")
        toFill.write("\n")
        toFill.write("\t#do other stuff")

    # execute newly created python file
    args = (
        "python",
        bFilePath
    )
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # use next line if the a.py has to wait until the subprocess execution is finished (in this case b.py)
    popen.wait()
    # you can get b.py´s results with this:
    resultOfSubProcess, errorsOfSubProcess = popen.communicate()
    print(str(resultOfSubProcess)) # outputs: b'b.py was executed correctly!\r\n'
    print(str(errorsOfSubProcess)) # outputs: None

    # do other stuff
```

instead of creating a new code file and filling it with code you of course can simply copy an existing one as shown here:
[How do I copy a file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your `b.py` script could take the name of the directory as a parameter.  Access the first parameter passed to `b.py` with:

```
import sys
dirname = sys.argv[1]
```

Then iterate over the files in the named directory with:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    process(filename)
```

Also see `glob.glob` and `os.walk` for more options processing files.