# How to clone files with Python?

Tags: python, macos, filesystems, apfs

Using bash on macos I can create COW file clones with `cp -c`. Is there a Python library that provides the same functionality? The copy functions in shutil doesn't seem to mention cloning.

On APFS clones: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Features/Features.html

On BSD clonefile: http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/clonefile/

Comment: Is that a feature of the filesystem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: By any chance, are you looking for a cli solution?

Comment: do you just need a cow buffer? in python this is typically referred to as `mmap` I haven't been able to find any information on cow files on osx...

Comment: I take it back, I just found an article talking about APFS adding cow (among other things...)

Comment: python does not seem to support the bsd `copyfile` command (which is what cp -c relies on), so you'll have to make system calls as Dylan suggested.

Comment: @DylanB This is clearly not a duplicate of the questions you have linked to, would you mind undoing marking this is as a duplicate. I feel like it was pretty clear in the question that I was referring to COW file clones.

Comment: Flag retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python standard library does not support cloning files.

To clone a file using `cp -c` in a subprocess you can use this function:

```
def clonefile(source, dest):
    subprocess.check_output(["cp", "-c", source, dest])
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I marked this as a duplicate but didn't know the difference between copying and cloning.

This is the location of the instructions for copying files with as much detail as possible in Python:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html

It starts with the following warning:
**Warning Even the higher-level file copying functions (shutil.copy(), shutil.copy2()) cannot copy all file metadata.**

If what you want is an OS cloning of the file, you're going to need to run a system call.  That system call is going to need to be OS specific, and the call will be pulled from this question:
[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

So, look into the copy library and see if you can get enough detail, and if you can't use a system-specific call.

Comment: your reference to external commands may be useful, but the OP already covered that `shutil` is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: All the documentation I found pointed to shutil being as deep as Python goes....  I was a bit trigger happy on the answer, I admit.

Comment: And, bluntly, it wouldn't make much sense for Python to have standard libraries system-specific enough to keep up with the power of Bash, ksh, etc.  A compiled solution would need to do all sorts of system lookups and (potentially bug ridden) dancing to keep up.  So I'd say you're better off sticking with the tool that does what you specifically need.