# TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation What is wrong in my code?

Tags: python

I got an error,TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation .
I wrote codes in data.py,

```
import os
import cv2
import argparse
import numpy as np
import math

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('input_dir' ,help='input directory')
parser.add_argument('output_dir' ,help='out directory')

args = parser.parse_args()

def find_all_files(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

        for file in files:
            p=os.path.join(root, file)
            p=p.split("/")[len(p.split("/"))-2]
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(p)

            yield os.path.join(root, file)

dirname=args.output_dir
if not os.path.exists(dirname):
    os.mkdir(dirname)


folder_img = find_all_files(args.input_dir)
im =cv2.imread(folder_img)
cv2.imwrite(args.output_dir ,im)
```

When I run `python data.py ./photo ./copy_photo` ( I wanna read images from photo folder and put output images in copy_photo folder),the error happens.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?I wrote print(folder_img) under folder_img variable & find_all_files method but the print statement is not shown.

Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 175, in <module>
    im =cv2.imread(folder_img)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Comment: Please paste full traceback and just the error message

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I added traceback.If u know something,please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give `cv2.imread(folder_img)` a list of files, it accepts *one* file.

See [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)

If you are not doing anything to the image in between, just [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) it.

else use

```
for f in folder_img:
    im =cv2.imread(f)
    # do your stuff
    cv2.imwrite(args.output_dir ,im)
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur code,but OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 459 error happens.What should I fix this?

Comment: name, ext = os.path.splitext(p) is useless.

Comment: @user9287271 debug what kind of file you are trying to write and search the `cv2.imwrite` API if it allows this kind of file. If not, goolge/search for `cv2 +  write + your extension` and see what pops up. If nothing pops up, create a new questions aka "How to write thisfielname.extension with `cv2.imwrite()`" detailing what you are doing in between imread() and imwrite()