# Duplicate a file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate a single file for example: I have a file in "C:\ ..." and would like to duplicate this exact same file once. If also possible is there a way to use python to open specific documents?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for [`copy2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2). This will copy the file contents and as much of the file metadata (permissions, ownership, etc) as it can on the platform. [`copystat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copystat) has more notes on what can and can't be copied and how to find out on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

just using system() from os module

```
os.system("cp resource_file target_file")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a module named **shutil**, the function **copy2** can be called with the path of the source file and the corresponding destination directory you want to write to. For example,

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2('/src/test.txt','/dst/test_copy.txt')
```

Comment: I like your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can copy a file via the command line on windows: open cmd.exe then type `cd "C:\ ..."` then type `copy yourfile destination`. [more info here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-copy-command-syntax-examples/)

you can make **python** do this for you: you will need the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module which comes integrated into python so you dont have to donwload anything.

like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('copy yourfile destionation')
```

remember that for this to work your python script should be in the same folder as "yourfile", why? because i type "yourfile" as a relative path [relative vs absolute path](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

subprocess works for **python 3.3 and newer versions** so another way to do it would be:

```
import os
os.system('copy youfile destionation')
```

to open specific  documents with python take a quick look at here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python