# csv to txt in python

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple .csv files in the fodler and I need to convert them to .txt files. Currently I am able just to rename them, but I want to leave the original files in place

```
import os,sys
folder = 'C:....'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
   infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
   if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
   oldbase = os.path.splitext(filename)
   newname = infilename.replace('.csv', '.txt')
   output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

Comment: Do you just want to change the file-extension, or do you also want to change the content of the csv?

Comment: Copy file then rename the copy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You are just making another copy with '.txt' extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copyfile of shutil.

```
import shutil

....< part of your code > ...
shutil.copyfile(filename, filename.replace('.csv', '.txt'))
```