# Copy from Directory save to USB

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

I'm working on a project of mine. I want to copy a folder or file from a computer to my say USB stick. 
something along the lines of

```
    Original = open("Original.txt", "r")
    Copy = open('Copied.txt','w')
```

Just what do I add to make this run.

Let me just go into more depth here:

say I have a computer with a file on it, I know the file name and want to take it from the computer and save it on the USB stick that I inserted.

how do I tell my computer where to safe file and how do I load it.

Comment: take a look at your recommended/related questions. The answer is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **shutil** module to copy files.

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src="C:/Test/Original.txt", dst="F:/Original.txt")  
# This copies the same file from SRC (Source) into the DST (destination) USB (say F: drive) while retaining the filename.
```

Comment: You forgot a `"` at the end of the src argument

Comment: Thanks @LouisSaglio for pointing that out. Answer updated. :)