# How to increment a variable (with number) inside python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Below given python script, I am trying to copy a text file and trying to create 10 copies of the same file as shown below:

```
logs1.txt
logs2.txt
.
.
logs10.txt
```

Basically i need to increment only the number present in destination text file name.

I have tried using "for loop" with range command. But I dont know how to increment a number inside a cp command.

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

class RunCmd(object):
    def cmd_run(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        subprocess.call(self.cmd, shell=True)


a = RunCmd()
a.cmd_run('cp /sh/awlog/Logs_new_1.txt /sh/logs/logs1.txt')
```

Comment: Looks like a convoluted way of doing something simple. Why are you creating a class to do this? Take a look at `shutil` module. Also, learn basics of python string operations.

Comment: there are several ways to achieve that. You could have a for loop in range(10) which run the same cmd command and update the name of the target file by concatenate the num to the string. '/sh/logs/logs' + num + '.txt'

Comment: Agreed, and if you really want that, at least associate the command in the `RunCmd` constructor, e.g. https://gist.github.com/fcracker79/d971c2a903a08c80ee8148ad00af667a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
templ = 'cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_{0}.txt /sh/logs/logs{0}.txt'
for num in range(1,11):
    print(templ.format(num))
```

output

```
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_1.txt /sh/logs/logs1.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_2.txt /sh/logs/logs2.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_3.txt /sh/logs/logs3.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_4.txt /sh/logs/logs4.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_5.txt /sh/logs/logs5.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_6.txt /sh/logs/logs6.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_7.txt /sh/logs/logs7.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_8.txt /sh/logs/logs8.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_9.txt /sh/logs/logs9.txt
cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_10.txt /sh/logs/logs10.txt
```

Comment: @RoadRunner the fact that the OP will need to pass the formatted string to `a.cmd_run()` is obvious enough.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Fair enough, I've removed my comment. I'm just suggesting a reason to why this answer was *probably* downvoted.

Comment: @RoadRunner Fair enough too ;-)

Comment: Also, OP question is effectively how to increment the number within the string. Most of the other answers are more focused on how to copy the file.

Answer (score 4):

It should be as simple as

```
import shutil

for i in range(10):
    shutil.copyfile('/path/to/source/file','/destination/path/logs'+str(i+1)+'.txt')
```

There's no need to create a class to carry out such simple functionality. Also, copying files can be done using the `shutil` module directly rather than creating a subprocess to do so.

More information about `shutil`: [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Edit:

alternate code as per Bruno's suggestions:

```
import shutil

for i in range(1,11):
    shutil.copyfile('/path/to/source/file','/destination/path/logs{}.txt'.format(i))
```

Comment: You should use string formatting instead of string concatenation, and `range()` can take a `start` argument so you don't need the `i+1` at all.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers at that point it's pretty much more about looks than anything else but yeah, that is some alternate syntax. (Unless you _really_ need to worry about performance, of course)

Comment: it's not "pretty much about looks than anything else" but about writing readable idiomatic code. Readiblity is highly valued by python programmers.

Comment: The difference in readability between these two particular examples is opinion-based. Somebody might see the `10` as clearly showing that there is exactly 10 iterations. Others might prefer the other syntax. Also, in this situation, as there isn't a lot of different variables to be concatenated, you could make a case for either concatenation or using `format`. In any case, I've provided the alternate syntax you suggested as well.

Answer (score 4):

> The [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) module offers a number of high-level operations on files and collections of files. In particular, functions are provided which support file copying and removal.

```
import shutil

for i in range(10):
    shutil.copyfile(
        "/sh/awlog/Logs_new_1.txt",
        "/sh/logs/logs{}.txt".format(i+1)
    )
```

Comment: @RoadRunner No.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `a.cmd_run` command-argument contains a string, you can just change this string in a while-loop.

```
i = 1
while i < 11:
    string = 'cp /sh/ec_rawlog/Logs_new_1.txt /sh/logs/logs%s.txt' % i
    a = RunCmd()
    a.cmd_run(string)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but you can also do this the old fashioned way:

```
# Open main file
with open("/sh/awlog/Logs_new_1.txt") as f_in:

    # Read in text
    file_str = f_in.read()

    # Iterate 1 - 10
    for i in range(1, 11):

        # Open new file to write to with number
        with open("/sh/logs/logs%d.txt" % i, mode="w") as f_out:
            f_out.write(file_str)
```

You can simply iterate over `range(1, 11)` to get the numbers 1 - 10, excluding 11. You can have a look at [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) for behavior specifics.

Addtionally, as pointed out in the other answers, the good thing about [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) is that it avoids the need to open files, as shown above, and you can copy the content over directly with no issues.

Having said this, the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py#L225) does still open files under the hood, so I guess that's something to consider.