# Capture directory name while creating it in loop

Tags: python

I have a list with folder names, for which I need to create directories in the current location and copy files into those created directories. Because files need to be copied to correct directories I am using a loop to go over each folder name in the list, create a directory based on the folder name and then copy files into it. Creating directories based on elements in the list is not a problem. The problem for me is how to capture those created directories in each loop iteration so that I can use it in my path when copying files in the next step.

Here is what I've tried:

```
dir = ['aaa','bbb')
for dir in dir_list:
    print os.mkdir(path)
```

Folders are successfully created in current working directory during loop execution. But I also need to capture its names. I have printed results which shows that os.mkdir returns "*None*". How can I get created directory names in the loop instead of "*None*" object?

Comment: While you're iterating with 'for dir in dir_list:' 'dir' is the name of the directory you're creating.

Comment: The path of directory is what you are giving as the argument to `os.mkdir()`.

Comment: And `os.mkdir()` is supposed to return `None` when successful.

Comment: you already have the names, you used them to make the directories in the first place.

Comment: is your problem to get the *absolute* name of the directory? this would be `os.path.abspath(path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the names of the folders are the paths you pass to `os.kdir()`. However, you can also directly copy the files to the folders just after creating the directory/ folder with the help of `shutil`. This can be done like in the following:

```py
import os 
import shutil


root    = "root/"
folders = ['path_to_dir/dir1', 'path_to_dir/dir2', 'path_to_dir/dir3']
fnames  = ['path_to_file/file1','path_to_file/file2','path_to_file/file2']

for folder in folders:
    try: 
        os.makedir(root + folder)
    except: 
        print("Error creating folder: ", folder)

    for fname in fnames:
        try:
            src_path = root + fname
            dst_path = root + folder + "/" + fname.split("/")[-1]

            shutil.copyfile(src_path, dst_path)
        except:
            print("Couldn't copy file: ", fname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I cannot use "shutil" cause I am copying files from Hadoop but your answer worked OK after adaptation to my case.

Comment: Glad it helped :) As a work-around  `shutil` you can use `os.popen`, or `os.system` or `subprocess`. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python), the answer by @kmario23 gives a wide variety of alternatives to `shutil`.