# How to save a df into two excel files in multiple locations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

Im trying to save the excel file generated in two different folders (output1, output2)

I tried this and didnt worked

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter([output1,output2], engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheeta', index = None)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the file using [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) after you created it *once* ... or simply write it twice:

```
import pandas as pd

output1 = "p.xlsx"
output2 = "q.xlsx"
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

for o in [output1,output2]:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(o, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

Results in 2 files being written, containing the data:

[image: xlxs content]

Doku:

- [xlswriter and pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)