# Copy all files from network drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a network drive that requires credentials to map.  I'd like to copy all files from that network folder to a local folder using Python 3.5+.

I was successfully using Powershell's

```
"New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -Root $ip_address -Credential $password -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Persist"
```

but am trying to switch all my scripts to Python.

I've created a local folder but I'm not sure how to navigate with a network drive.

```py
#Creating destination folder
pathlib.Path(my_target_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

I don't even need to map the drives if it's not necessary.  Just wanting to copy all files in that directory to my local directory.

Comment: Check this question, it might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: That's interesting but it's unclear how to source from a network drive that requires credentials (e.g. 10.10.10.5 password=1234)...