# How do I copy a file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to copy a file using Julia functions with the hope of manipulating the file and then use that copied version for various tasks in the Julia programming language. Can someone provide some example code of copying a file in Julia?

I guess I could do use `read` then `write` but it seems like I would be reinventing the wheel.
Is there a standard library function for this?

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use the built in function [`cp(src, dst)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.cp).

> Copy the file, link, or directory from `src` to `dst`. `force=true` will first remove an existing `dst`.

Afterwards you can [`open`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open) the file and manipulate it. Of course you could also open both source an destination files simultaneously and copy and manipulate it line by line.