# python - How to copy files from one directory to another only if the file is not present in destination?

Tags: python

I would like to check the file by its name and copy from the src_dir to dest_dir in their respective folders if that file is not present in dest_dir.

For example, I have a

src_dir

- firstfolder

  - file1
  - file3
  - file4
- secondfolder

  - file1
  - file2
- anotherfolder

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt

dest_dir

- firstfolder

  - file1
  - file2
- secondfolder

  - file1
- athirdfolder
- anotherfolder

  - file.txt

The result should be ,

dest_dir

- firstfolder

  - file1
  - file2
  - file3
  - file4
- secondfolder

  - file1
  - file2
- athirdfolder
- anotherfolder

  - file.txt
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt

Comment: Please post the code that you already tried (minimized so that it works without other things that aren't related) So we can help you better. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python).

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile

filename = 'file.ext'
src_dir = 'src/'
dst_dir = 'dst/'

if not os.path.isfile(dst_dir + filename):
   copyfile(src_dir + filename, dst_dir + filename)
```

If you wish to do so for each file in a directory :

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile
import glob

src_dir = 'src/'
dst_dir = 'dst/'

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_dir, '*')):
    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path) and not os.path.isfile(dst_dir + filename):
        copyfile(file_path, dst_dir + filename)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried this, But it always gives the foldername and not the file name.

Comment: For nested directories, you may use a recursive approach. Or if you know the depth of the directories, hard-code it. For example, you could check if `file_path` is a directory with `os.path.isdir` and if it's the case start the same protocol (`for sub_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path, '*')` ...).