# How to copy all files named with a particilar name to a new location?

Tags: python, copy

I want to copy all files named `alertmap` to a new location with the same name as of its parent folder( or within a new folder named the same as its parent folder).

```py
import glob
for file1 in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\mabrol\\Desktop\\boxing\\*\\AlertMap1.txt"):
    print(file1)

for file2 in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\mabrol\\Desktop\\boxing\\*\\AlertMap1.txt"):
    print(file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the library before but [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) they suggest `shutil`-library. It is also explained how it works and what is propably best to use.

Naming the files with a specific pattern is pretty easy and shouldn't be a big issue here.