# How to use cmd in Python 3

Tags: python, cmd

I have the following problem: from a Python script I need to run a CMD where I use 3 parameters, like below:

```
path_to/my.exe path/file.abc > path/file.txt
```

The closest solution found till now is something like:

```
os.system("start cmd /k D:/.../myexecutable.exe D:/.../file1.dat > D:/.../file1.txt")
```

But this only creates a blank file called `file1.txt`, and in console I have the output produced by my EXE visible, but that content is not redirected to text file as I expect.

Also it will be nice to hide the console during the execution and wait for finish.

This part shall be applied to multiple files (this I manage to do).

---

Applying info from comments now the text is in the file, using this code:

```
os.system("cmd /k D:\\...\\myexecutable.exe D:\\...\\file1.dat ^> D:\\...\\file1.txt")
```

Left with one problem: in the command window, at end of file processing it's printed the path to my Python file. How can I close it?

Comment: What is the purpose of `start` in your code? Note that the Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`…

Comment: I've used start simply because I took it from an example ....

Comment: Are you getting the line to run from a third-party? Because it would be simpler to use `subprocess` to run your binary, and redirect the subprocess's stdout to whatever file you want. Alternatively, you can shove the entire thing to run in `subprocess` using `shell=True`, that's less safe and reliable but it should also work fine.

Comment: Following @aschipfl suggestion, I've removed the start from the string and replaced all / with \\. Now something is better, a blank console is opened, but after waiting a while I close it manually. I've checked the txt file and now contains all the info I need. So, how can i force the console to close when the execution is finished?

Comment: you need to escape the `>` character to stop it being consumed by `cmd`. The usual way to do that is to use the caret escape character, `^`.

Comment: @Masklinn: shame on me but I'm completely new to this level of programming. Resuming, I have one exe file, let's call it a.exe and a b.dat file. I know to use it in command, like that:<br/> a.exe b.dat > b.txt<br/> how can I translate this to a subprocess call?

Comment: @Compo: as I said a bit ago, now I manage to have the info written in my txt file but i don't know how to make the cmd window to close when the execution is completed.

Comment: `with open('b.dat', 'wb') as out: subprocess.run(['a.exe'], stdout=out)` should do the trick. You may want to add e.g. `check=True` in case you want an exception to be raise should the command signal a failure.

Comment: Use `cmd`'s `/c` option, instead of its `/k` option!

Comment: @Adrian the entire point of the `/K` flag is to run the command *then keep the shell alive*, so maybe don't do that, and use `/C` instead (runs the command then shuts down)?

Comment: Look at this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python?rq=1
maby it solves you Propleme

Comment: Using @Compo's tips I manage to make it work, also I will try later the solution form Masklinn. Thank you guys!

Comment: I [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post twice now to show you how it could/should look like; next time when you edit it, please format it correctly on your own!

Comment: Instead of ecaping the redirection character, `os.system("cmd /c D:/.../myexecutable.exe D:/.../file1.dat ^> D:/.../file1.txt")`, you could alternatively try quoting your, `/c`, option: `os.system("cmd /c \"D:/.../myexecutable.exe D:/.../file1.dat > D:/.../file1.txt\"")`