# Python - How to copy a file to the new location with a different name

Tags: python

Here i am trying to copy a file from a source location to the target location.

```
from shutil import copy2
sourcefile = "file.avro"
targetdirectory = "/home"
copy2(soucefil,targetdirectory)
```

But i need to copy the file to the new location with a different name say file.avro.copy
Is there any python library that can be used for renaming file while copying itself. Donot want to copy and rename in two different steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Comment: `copy2(soucefile, targetdirectory+"/"+sourcefile+".copy")`

Answer (score 1):

## Use shtutil function 'copyfile(old_path, new_path)':

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile('myfile.txt', '/home/myfileCopy.txt')
```