# After extracting the list of folder names in a directory, how do I rename them in another format using Python?

Tags: python, directory, rename

I want to cleanup my files and am currently stuck after extracting the list of folders in a directory. I want to extract the date portion of the folders and generate .txt files based on these dates.

Below code I used:

```
    import os

root ="C:\\Users\\Mr. Slowbro\\Desktop\\Test Python\\"
dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
print (dirlist)
```

The output is as below list:

['01 Jan 20 - Alpha', '08 Sept 19 - Bravo', '31 Dec 18 - Receipt Folder']

How do I get the following output and generate them as .txt files in another folder?

eg.

01 Jan 20.txt

08 Sept 19.txt

31 Dec 18.txt

Comment: `shututil.copyfile`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, we are required to create a `.txt` file for every directory name commensurate with the name in the question.

We can [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) every directory on `-` and build the filename like:

```py
import os
target_dir = "path\\to\\directory\\"
for _dir in dirlist:
    filename = _dir.split("-")[0].strip() + ".txt" # get the date and add extension
    filepath = os.path.join(target_dir, filename)
    with open(filepath, "w") as f: pass # create file
```