# Why is there no os.copy() under the standard os module?

Tags: python, file, copy

Python's `os` module has `.remove`, `.rename`, and other file-related functions.

Why is there no support for `.copy`?

I found [how to copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python) and it seems `shutil` is the go-to library.

---

I was wondering about the process that led to the decision not to include a basic file copy in `os`

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/ciEZAzRR6dg/TNT9xnzyV9cJ

Answer (score 4):

The `os` module was designed to hold OS-level functionality, and "copy" isn't OS-level functionality. Stuff like `os.remove`, `os.rename`, etc. correspond to low-level filesystem operations, while "copy" is a much higher-level operation.

Comment: Could you elaborate please on why these functionalities considered of different abstraction levels? This is the first time i heared this, don't even know what to google.