# shutil error: "Module 'shutil' has no 'copy' member"

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.7, shutil

I am still learning python but got stuck here:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil
p = Path.home()
shutil.copy(p / 'G:\souce.txt', p / 'G:\dest.text')
```

The error is:

```
shutil: shutil
Anomalous backslash in string: '\s'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.pylint(anomalous- 
backslash-in-string)
Anomalous backslash in string: '\d'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.pylint(anomalous- 
backslash-in-string)
Module 'shutil' has no 'copy' memberpylint(no-member)
```

Not able to go for the next step. So any suggestions please.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to concatenate `G:\souce.txt` ? Is there where the file located?

Comment: I just want to copy the content of the file souce.txt to G:\dest.txt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
import shutil 
shutil.copy('G:\souce.txt', 'G:\dest.text')
```