# How to make multiple copies of a unique file resulting in different files names

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I have one unique file "`C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\EXTRACT\BON_B000.IMG.5.3.txt`" and now I need to copy this file in more than 400 files with unique names, with exactly the same content but with different names.

The file names do not have any order or any logic, I have a list with them.

I tryed to use shuntil.copy but I was not able to do that with multiple files at same time..

```
import os
import shutil
path = '/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT'

print("Before copying file: ")
print(os.listdir(path))

source = path+"/BON_B000.IMG.5.3.txt"

destination=  
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R160.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R161.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R170.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R180.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R190.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_B081.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SNW_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS02.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS03.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS04.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_BS05.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I100.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I101.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I102.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I103.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I110.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I120.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I130.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I210.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I310.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I400.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I500.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I700.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I710.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I810.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_I900.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_IB10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_RA00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_RA10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_RB00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/TWR_RB10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B010.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B060.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B071.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B160.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B170.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B180.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B190.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B200.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B210.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B220.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B230.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B240.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B250.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B260.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B270.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B280.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B290.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B300.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_B310.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_BS02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WAL_BS03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF04.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF05.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF06.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF07.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF08.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF09.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BF11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS02.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS03.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WD1_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF04.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF05.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF07.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BF08.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/WST_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_B150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_BS02.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_BS04.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_BS05.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_E170.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_E171.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_E172.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BON_OS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BTL_SMP1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BTL_SMP4.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BTL_SMP5.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BTL_SMP8.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/BTL_SMP9.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B011.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B021.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B042.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B081.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B091.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_B111.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF04.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF05.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF06.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF07.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF08.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF09.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BF10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS04.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/CV1_BS12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_BS20.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DRL_BS30.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B160.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_B170.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/DST_BS20.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_B160.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/ESL_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B00A.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B00B.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B01A.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B01B.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B02A.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B02B.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B03A.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B03B.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B04A.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_B04B.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_BS02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/GRB_BS03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B160.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_B170.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_BS12.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_BS13.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HEL_E140.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HTW_PMP1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/HTW_PMPK.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JGL_BS12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS21.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS31.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS32.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS33.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BS41.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BSS0.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BSS1.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BSS2.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BSS3.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_BSS4.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM04.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM05.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/JUL_RM06.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B041.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/LAK_BS13.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MGC_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MGC_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MGC_JWL0.IMG.5.5.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MHM_GDN1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B120.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B130.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B140.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_B150.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_BS02.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MIN_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_B181.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF13.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF14.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF15.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF16.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF17.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF18.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BF19.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS20.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS21.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS30.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS31.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/MNT_BS33.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B050.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B060.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B070.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B080.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B090.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B100.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_B110.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_BS10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_BS11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/RUI_BS12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_B151.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF00.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF01.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF02.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF03.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF10.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF11.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF12.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF13.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF14.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF15.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF16.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BF17.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BS02.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEA_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_BSS0.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNI0.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNI1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNI2.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNI3.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNL0.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNL1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNL2.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNL3.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNR0.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNR1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_MNR2.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC0.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC1.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC2.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC3.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC4.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC5.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC6.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC7.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SEI_SNC8.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_BS00.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_BS01.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_BS10.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_BS11.IMG.5.4.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_DK32.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_DK41.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R000.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R010.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R020.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R030.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R040.IMG.5.3.txt",
"/Users/alexa/Desktop/INSERT/SHP_R050.IMG.5.3.txt"

dest = shutil.copy(source, destination)

print("After copying file: ")
print(os.listdir(path))

print("Destination path: ", dest)
```

And I got a *invalid syntax*.

I think I should put a loop here, but I don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There isn't a way to copy that file to 400 places with one command. You will need a loop or something and shutil has a function for copy a file from one place to the other while changing name. Can you show what you tried and what didn't work and maybe we can work off that.

Comment: if you have the 400 file names in a list, just loop over the list. Each iteration make a copy of the file using the given name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Is `destination` supposed to be a list? Then you need to surround it with `[]`.

Comment: And how can I loop over my list?

Comment: I showed you in my answer below how you do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy).
This question is a duplicate of this: [How do I copy a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python)

```
file_name_suffix = range(1,401)    
file = "/path/to/file.txt"
destination_prefix = "/path/to/newfile"
for i in file_name_suffix:
   file_destination = destination_prefix + str(i) + ".txt"
   shutil.copyfile(file, file_destination)
```

Comment: Hi. This question is not a duplication of "How do I copy a file in Python" or I didn't get the point. Seeing this trhead I am not able to find a solution for duplicating one file multiple times using different names. Could you show me?

Comment: The loop does this for you. You loop over the numbers between 1 and 400, create a new file name with the numbers, and the file is copied through shutil.copyfile