# Python - Paste document to each folder in directory

Tags: python, shutil

I have an annual file located on our netwrok that contains sub-folders based on each week of the year.  I am trying to write a script that will copy a "Template" document saved on my desktop, then iterate through the annual file, and paste the Template into each weekly sub-folder.

I have a script that is generating a "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" though I am not sure why, and therefore not sure what to do about it.

```
import os
import shutil

myPath = r"""K:\PROCESS\YEAR"""
myDocument = r"""C:\Users\me.domain\OneDrive - Co Name\Desktop\Template.xlsx"""

for filename in os.listdir(myPath):
    with open(os.path.join(myPath,filename)) as myFile:
        copyfile(myDocument, myFile)
```

Error is,

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘K:\PROCESS\YEAR\WEEK 1’
```

@ line 'with open(os.path.join(myPath,filename)) as myFile:'

I tried moving the target document to the program root and modified the script based on some sugestions as seen below.

```
import os
from shutil import copy2

my_doc_path = "Template.xlsx"
myPath = "K:\PROCESS\YEAR"

for directory in os.listdir(myPath):
    copy2(my_doc_path, directory)
```

I am no longer receiving any errors; however, the target document is not being coppied to the target directory. Instead, a nondescript "file" with the target directory name is being created in the program root as seen in the image below.

[image]

---

What ended up working:

```
import os
from shutil import copy

my_doc_path = "Template.xlsx"
myPath = "K:\PROCESS\YEAR"

for directory in os.listdir(myPath):
    
    target_directory = myPath + '\\' + directory
    check_file = target_directory + '\\' + my_doc_path
    
    if not os.path.exists(check_file):
        copy(my_doc_path, target_directory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document name needed to be appended to myPath variable.  I incorrectly assumed the copy2() function was looking for the path to save the document to, I didnt realize it required the full destination path including the document itself.

Thanks for the feedback everyone, it got me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening a file, try to copy your file in the target folders.

```
from shutil import copy

my_doc_path = "/here/is/my/doc/path.xlsx"
myPath = "K:\PROCESS\YEAR"

for directory in os.listdir(myPath):
    copy(my_doc_path, directory)
```

Or if you need also the metadata:

```
from shutil import copy2

my_doc_path = "/here/is/my/doc/path.xlsx"
myPath = "K:\PROCESS\YEAR"

for directory in os.listdir(myPath):
    copy2(my_doc_path, directory)
```

Why `copy/copy2` instead of `copyfile`? take a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359308/7597536)

Comment: I think you should rather use copy2, as it copies metadata too.

Comment: (Unless of course the OP doesn't want that, but he didn't mention that)

Comment: Yes, of course, it depends of what is the OP needs :) (add also the copy2 example)

Comment: So, it dosnt look like this is copying the targt file "my_doc_path" to the the target folder, it looks like it is creating a "file" with the target folder name in the application root.  The file has no file type, jsut the name of the target folder