# how to save a file in a folder using python

Tags: python

files Is not saving in that  folder
this is the code I'm using can anyone help with this

```
import os
folder_name='my_folder'
entries='['Air Products.pdf', 'My.xlsx', 'Payment.xlsx']'
for i in range(len(entries)):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder_name)):
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder_name, entries[i])
        print(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder_name, entries[i]))
```

Comment: You haven't set a `folder_name` so it's just joining in the current working directory with your filename.

Comment: What's your folder name ?

Comment: Get out of the habit of `for i in range(len(entries))`. Use `for entry in entries:`

Comment: my_folder is my folder name

Comment: You're not saving anything, you're just printing the pathname.

Comment: ```filePath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder_name, entries[i])``` You are just appending the entries to the path.

Comment: Why don't you just `print(filePath)`? What's the point of assigning the variable if you're not going to use it?

Comment: Are you trying to copy files? It's not clear from your question what "saving files" means.

Comment: yes I'm copying the file from another folder

Comment: i just wanted the files in that folder

Comment: @Sandeepkumar where are your files located originally?

Comment: You can go through this: [How can a file be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-can-a-file-be-copied)