# I want to save my random choiced images in my folder

Tags: python, random, save

```py
import os, random
import numpy
from PIL import Image

path = "C:/Users/mark03/Desktop/rmv_1_loan_0908/images"
save_path = "C:/Users/mark03/Desktop/rmv_1_loan_0908/random"

file_list = os.listdir(path)
def selectRandom(file_list):
    return numpy.random.choice(file_list, 3, False)

print(selectRandom(file_list))
```

Hi there!
I want to save 'my random choiced images' in my folder.
But in this code,

I just check image names, but these images are not saved in my folder.
So I want to plus code about save in my folder.

Is there any good way to solve the problem???
thank you!

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: you need to iterate over the random file list using `for ... in` and save them to destination, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python