# How do I send a file to an external folder simply?

Tags: python, directory, file-transfer

Now, before this question gets reported as a duplicate, I have searched all other questions but they just don't work for me. I want to send an image from the current working directory to an external folder.

```py
crnt={current-working-directory}
dest={destination-folder}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-to-copy-files)

Comment: `os.replace()` ?

Comment: What have tried (in Python)?

Comment: There's no point telling us that every existing solution doesn't work for you without telling us *why* they didn't work. What's so unique about your situation? Without knowing that there's no way for us to suggest anything other than the options that already worked for everyone else.

Comment: Just try `shutil.move`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy then go with this

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

If you want to move then you could use

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score -1):

You could use os like this:

```
import os

crnt={file-location}
dest={file-destination}    
os.system(f"mv {crnt} {dest}")
```

Or for a more traditional way you could do this:

```
crnt={file-location}
dest={file-destination} 

with open(f"{crnt}", "rb") as ogFile:
    bData = ogFile.read()

with open(f"{dest}", "wb") as destFile:
    destFile.write(bData)
```

Comment: The shutil module has better options